# Diksha with regards to devotional mantras?

Tags: mantras

I have already asked a similar question myself,and and have seen questions of this sort being answered.

I do know that Agamas mandate Diksha ,to chant mantras.

My doubt is [this](https://youtu.be/EcPmuc7zIkI) video in which Swami Shivananda’s instructions for mantra jaap are presented.

**If Diksha is such an important prelude to mantra chanting,then surely it should have been mentioned**

So what is amiss?Is the video wrong for not mentioning Diksha?Or is there other reasons why Swamiji’s instructions did not mention Diksha?

Comment: Diksha is a neccessary element, but mentioning "one needs to take Diksha first" would constrain people. Ultimately, no one would do japa. Its definitely worth to start practicing insted of waiting and doing nothing. I personally just have one concern, although they listed many mantras some are not suitable to everyone. Thus I say one must just proceed to chant nama insted of mantra. Hence one must not place 'om'  at the start.

Comment: But I’ve read somewhere that if we wrongly chant/omit or add to mantras as we wish,the consequences can be permanent insanity or even death.Don’t know whether we can actually avoid the Omkara...

Comment: Please do not video links as reference. If you have a specific question then put it in your question.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda I’m sorry I couldn’t get what yourself was trying to say.My question was as to why Swami Shivananda did not mention Diksha in the context of mantra jaap .I used the video only so that there is proof and others may watch the video themselves.